# How do I put out burning teammates?

Tags: xcom-2

A teammate ran through some fire and is now affected by "Burning", which causes 3 damage per turn.  I'd like to put it out so I don't have to use a medkit.  How do I put out a burning teammate?

Comment: If you already have to use a medkit, that will also put out fires.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have the burning member run through a tile that contains water. This will put out your soldier and remove the Burning debuff.

This can include tiles such as Fountains on certain tilesets or puddles, even the green goo encountered in the first Blacksite mission you go through.  If the weather is raining it will not put out the fire.

Medkits will also remove any status debuff, like Burning or Poisoned.

Comment: I have seen the AI do this as well - also burning is 1-3 dmg at the start of the units round

Comment: If using a medkit puts it out, you should add that to the answer. A medkit gets rid of acid. Probably gets fire, as Aurelius says.

Comment: Gremlin heal also does it.

Comment: in WotC, the burning teammate can also Hunker Down to remove burning.